# Print all integers that are greater than their left neighbor

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, integer, python-3.6

(Using python 3) Here is the task I have been given:

Given a list of numbers, find and print all its elements that are greater than their left neighbor.

Example input

```
1 5 2 4 3
```

Example output

```
5 4
```

Here is my code:

```
# creates a list out of the input given as '# # # # # #...'
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]

for i in a[1:]:               #skips the first since it has no "left neighbor"
   if i > a[a.index(i) - 1]:  #checks if 'i' is greater than element before 'i'
      print(i, end=' ')
```

My issue is that it works for all the tests I do except if I give it a list where `a[0] == a[-1]` then it ignores all of the elements in the list equal to that integer.

for example:

```
3 5 2 3 1 2 3 1 3
--> 5
```

I've been having a hard time finding the bug! Please excuse me if this question is not well presented. Is the first time I've asked a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: the function .index(a) finds the first value in the array that is equal to a, so if the values in the array are not unique it will not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] > a[i-1]:
        print(a[i], end=' ')
```

Result:

```
3 5 2 3 1 2 3 1 3
--> 5 3 2 3 3
```

Comment: The for loop starts at i = 1, so it should be fine.

Comment: No sir it won't. I'm not starting the loop from 0th index.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the 1.

Answer (score 4):

Using `filter` and `lambda`:

```
lst = [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]

greater = [item[1] for item in filter(lambda x: x[1] > x[0], zip(lst, lst[1:]))]
print(greater)
```

Which yields

```
[5, 3, 2, 3, 3]
```

Or, as @Roadrunner comments (my favourite!):

```
[y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if y > x]
```

Just to confuse the masses, you could as well write your own generator function:

```
def greater(iterable):
    ilst = iter(iterable)
    prev, current = None, next(ilst)
    while (ilst):
        if prev and current > prev:
            yield current
        prev, current = current, next(ilst)

greater_n = [g for g in greater(lst)]
print(greater_n)
```

---

Timing this (a 100.000 times each):

```
def mushif():
    lst = [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
    greater = []
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[i] > lst[i-1]:
            greater.append(lst[i])

def jan():
    lst = [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
    greater = [item[1] for item in filter(lambda x: x[1] > x[0], zip(lst, lst[1:]))]


def roadrunner():
    lst = [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
    greater = [y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if y > x]

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(mushif, number=10**5))
print(timeit.timeit(jan, number=10**5))
print(timeit.timeit(roadrunner, number=10**5))
```

Yields

```
0.37175918000139063
0.49957343799906084
0.2700801329992828
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this method over mushif's? I get the point but if I would spot this in production and another context it would definitely take more time to understand. So is it faster?

Comment: 3 years later and I see how trivial this is! I would definitely reach for a list comp now!

Answer (score 3):

One more sulution without using `zip` or accessing element every time by it's index

```
prev, *lst = [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
greater = []
for i in lst:
    if prev < i:
        greater.append(i)
    prev = i
```

And test cases as @Jan presented:

```
def mushif(lst):
    greater = []
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[i] > lst[i-1]:
            greater.append(lst[i])

def jan(lst):
    greater = [item[1] for item in filter(lambda x: x[1] > x[0], zip(lst, lst[1:]))]


def roadrunner(lst):
    greater =   [y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if y > x]

def vishes_shell(lst):
    start, *lst = lst
    greater = []
    for i in lst:
        if start < i:
            greater.append(i)
        start = i

import timeit, functools, random
lst = [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
print('Runnig with {} elements'.format(lst))
print('mushif', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(mushif, lst), number=10**5))
print('jan', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(jan, lst), number=10**5))
print('roadrunner', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(roadrunner, lst), number=10**5))
print('vishes_shell', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(vishes_shell, lst), number=10**5))

lst = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]
print('Runnig with 100 elements')
print('mushif', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(mushif, lst), number=10**5))
print('jan', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(jan, lst), number=10**5))
print('roadrunner', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(roadrunner, lst), number=10**5))
print('vishes_shell', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(vishes_shell, lst), number=10**5))

lst = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(1000)]
print('Runnig with 1000 elements')
print('mushif', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(mushif, lst), number=10**5))
print('jan', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(jan, lst), number=10**5))
print('roadrunner', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(roadrunner, lst), number=10**5))
print('vishes_shell', timeit.timeit(functools.partial(vishes_shell, lst), number=10**5))
```

Outputs:

```
Runnig with [3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3] elements
mushif 0.22174075798830017
jan 0.367339823016664
roadrunner 0.16411117801908404
vishes_shell 0.16474426098284312

Runnig with 100 elements
mushif 1.8483440639975015
jan 2.6946504779916722
roadrunner 0.8267438650073018
vishes_shell 1.1597095750039443

Runnig with 1000 elements
mushif 21.29723681899486
jan 26.859666333009955
roadrunner 8.274298987002112
vishes_shell 12.677083582995692
```

As you can see `roadrunner` one's is the best.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
[a[i] for i in range(1,len(a)) if a[i] > a[i-1]]
# [5, 3, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice
greater = [y for x,y in zip(a,islice(a,1,None)) if x < y]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.